# Proxying HTTP POST with JSON contents

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, proxy, cors

We've hit some CORS issues and I'm trying to use server proxying to get around it, as that seems to most reliable means of handling it.  But I'm hitting major issues with POST requests.

The general structure of the proxy is:
`JQuery-based client -> WebServer HttpHandler Proxy -> WebAPI Service`

The client uses JSON payloads and expects them in return.

Example client:

```
ourcompany.datasource.postData({
    data: ko.toJSON(requestObject),
    success: function (response, status) { ourcompany.messenger.success('Thanks for the data!');},
    error: function () { ourcompany.messenger.fail('Oh no!'); }
}
```

We use amplify.js as well, which just adds some wrappers around the jquery underlying objects.  For completeness, here's the definition of the request, where the rest of the jquery.ajax parameters are at:

```
amplify.request.define('postData', 'ajax', {
    url: buildProxyUrl(outCompany.urls.svcData),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: addCustomHeaders,
    decoder: wrapperDecoder
});
```

Example webapi:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostData(PostDataRequest request)
{
      HttpResponseMessage response = null;
      var response = BusinessLayer.DoSomeStuff(request);
      return response;
}
```

This all works fine in the non-proxy situation.  As you can see, we create a complex .NET object through deserializing some JSON on the WebAPI side.

The proxy is screwing this all up.  Essentially, I can't figure out how to just send the JSON content of the  original request along the second request without it being messed up by the transfer.  The current code looks like this:

```
private void MakeHttpPostRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var url = context.Request["url"];
    var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Headers["x-customheader"] = context.Request.Headers["x-customheader"];

    var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(reqStream);
    reqStream.Close();
    context.Request.InputStream.Close();


    using (var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Write(content);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several other means of extracting the content and pushing onto the outgoing request, and nothing seems to work. In the best case, the WebAPI method gets called with a null value for the request object.  I have no idea where to go at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the request Content-Type header in your proxy. You also forgot to properly dispose all your IDisposable resources:

```
private void MakeHttpPostRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var url = context.Request["url"];
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;
    req.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;
    req.Headers["x-customheader"] = context.Request.Headers["x-customheader"];

    using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(reqStream);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
        stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, yeah, it was just the ContentType.  Also, that's a much cleaner way to handle the whole process, very nicely done.  I wish I could give you two +1s, but hopefully others will provide that!